# How to describe "return ref" in expression tree?

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

```
Func<T, TField> GetFunc<T, TField> (this FieldInfo fieldInfo) {
      var instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter (typeof (T), "instance");
      var fieldExpression = Expression.Field (instanceParameter, fieldInfo);
      var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TField>> (fieldExpression, instanceParameter);
      return lambda.Compile ();
}
```

I wrote this method to get this lambda expression.

```
return (T instance) => instance.[fieldInfo.Name];
```

But how do I write the method to get this lambda expression?

```
return (T instance) => ref instance.[fieldInfo.Name];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504598

Comment: ... There is CS8155 compiler error so I don't think if it's possible (create expression with ref return) ...

Comment: The first problem is that your delegate type doesn't return a `ref`. You'll have to declare your own delegate type: `public delegate ref TField RefReturner<T, TField>(T obj);`

Comment: ... but even with that, I suspect this is not possible. Expression trees are basically frozen in time from when they were introduced, and support for more recent C# features hasn't been added to them

Comment: also to extend on what @canton7 says (although IIRC some minor additions have been made): expression trees want to be able to work in fallback reflection mode for when the runtime doesn't allow IL-emit; and you can't work properly with `ref` values via reflection - hence I doubt it *would* be added

Comment: @MarcGravell I see, so can DynamicMethod(ILGenerator) do this?

Comment: at that point you're just talking `ILGenerator`, and yes: `ILGenerator` can handle both managed and unmanaged pointers just fine